# Change description order or category pages

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I wonder if its possible to change the description of one category to be just after the products.
Example here:
http://www.theprinterdepo.com/refurbished-printers/monochrome-laser-refurbished-printers

I suppose there is one phtml file somewhere that I could change easily for this

I found the file, and the code is as follow

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">

         <?php 
         //$currentPage = $this->getCollection()->getCurPage();
         echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') 
         ?>

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Howver the getCurPage gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get category id
$category = $category->load($category_id);


// get collection    
$category->getProductCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category)->addAttributeToSelect('*');    

// print out the description
echo $category->getDescription();


// get current page
$currentPage = $this->getCollection()->getCurPage();
if($currentPage = 1) {
   // show Description Here
   echo $category->getDescription();
} else {
   // Show category name instead of description
   echo $category->getName();
```

**-- EDIT --**
try this instead of above

```
$currentPage->getSelect()->getCurPage();
```

Comment: I am sorry, I had a mistaken on first answer.

Comment: is it possible to remove the description of all pages, so that it appears only in the first one?

Comment: try `$this->IsTopCategory()`, `$this->isFirstPage()`, `$this->isLastPage()` methods.

Comment: can you show me how to? I am not a real php developer just a webmaster that controls magento.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCurPage() on a non-object in /home/theprint/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/MAG060062/template/catalog/category/view.phtml on line 60

Answer (score 1):

the file you are looking for is located in theme folder under `catelog/category/view.phtml`. so if have any custom theme installed locate the file first in your theme, if the file is not there then you can copy the file from the base folder and put in your theme folder, be sure to put the file in the correct folder otherwise it will not going to work. Like
if file is located in 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`
put the file in 
`app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`.
This way if you upgrade the magento to newer version, the changes you made will not be over written by the system

Comment: is it possible to remove the description of all pages, so that it appears only in the first one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put Category description after product listing, you just need to move elements around.
The template you need to modify is this:
app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/category/view.phtml.
Take this code:

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and move it at the bottom of the file. That's it.